Django - the date field in the data entered form is reset during editing
I made a model, form and views. I added some data via form. And then when i want editing, all fields are full but datefield is empty. I want to see date which i added before. But nothing.
I use all ai solutions also javascript, jquery, but nothing.
How can i solve this problem.

I have model like this:
class Cilt(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Kullanıcı")
    birth_place = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Birth Place")
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Birth date")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"

forms.py
class CiltForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cilt
        exclude = ['user']
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'birth_place': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            }
 
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CiltForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance:
            initial_date = birth_date
            self.fields['birth_date'].initial = initial_date
            self.fields['birth_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'})

edit views
def cilt_duzenle(request, user_id):
    ciltler = get_object_or_404(Cilt, user__id=user_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CiltForm(request.POST, instance=ciltler)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('cilt_detay', user_id=user_id)
    else:
        form = CiltForm(instance=ciltler)
    return render(request, 'cilt/cilt_duzenle.html', {'form': form})

template
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <h2>Cilt Bilgilerini Edit</h2>

  
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
  </form>
  <a href="{% url 'cilt_detay' user_id=request.user.id %}">Geri Dön</a>

  
{% endblock %}


What happens if you remove the def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): function altogether?  Shouldn't form = CiltForm(instance=ciltler) do what you want already?

@raphael i remove the all def init section and still the same, datefield doesnt come

First, is the date not blank in the database (check the admin).  Second, you don't need fields = '__all__' since exclude = ['user'] already includes all fields except user.  Third, maybe add your template to your question.  It might shed some light on the problem.

@raphael i added template and template is so simple. In the database datefield not empty. It has a date. When i say empty field, it means when you look at image you will see gg.aa.yyyy , but i want forexample 02.07.2024 like this.

Try adding form = CiltForm(instance=ciltler) to the beginning of the def cilt_duzenle(request, user_id): function.  Otherwise, I'm out of ideas, and I will try to reproduce your error on my machine later.

@raphael i added still same. When you try my problem. Just made two field model and form, one is textinput other is dateinput. Make three views, add, detail and edit views. After add data and then edit. When you edit the datas with template page like mine, i just want date field must be 11.11.2024 instead of gg.aa.yyyy . Thank you so much.

I just tried and I can not reproduce the error.  On my machine the date is showing up as 11/11/2024 (my date format is different).  The error must be somewhere else, and I am not sure where.  I can try to troubleshoot further if you have a github you can share, but there is no more I can do here.  Sorry.

@raphael I haven't prepared the project yet, I gave you an early link, I also sent you a message from your website, can you take a look from there?

The issue is being caused by:
'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),.
Django renders DateInput as type 'text' instead of what you would expect (type 'date') because of the difficulty with this input since there are issues with it when using different time zones and local time formats.  There are ways to handle this, but I haven't found out how yet.
However, if you can do without the calendar widget then you don't need to set the type as date, but you will lose the calendar widget on the right side of the date input:

So change your form to this:
class CiltForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cilt
        exclude = ['user']

        widgets = {
            'birth_place': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            }


I liked using the calendar widget because I didn't want someone to get confused whether to put a period or / this between the numbers when entering the date, but it seems to be a problem. Thank you for your help.

I haven't tried this yet, @Prusa but you can try a plugin like https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/.

The date you are initializing is seems wrong.
initial_date = instance.ucuk_en_son_cikis_tarihi

Modify the code like this to solve the issue.
initial_date = instance.birth_date 


hi @Vinita my real code Turkish and i made a little bit simpler, so, your answer is same in my actual code but still same problem.

what exactly you are getting in Ciltinstance ciltler = get_object_or_404(Cilt, user__id=user_id). can you share here

i am getting specified user datas. Just think you made a personal info form, and then you wanna edit the form after saved data. Your date field not filled, still at the beginning. I wanna solve this.
